# Add a common legend under multiple ggplots with different input

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, legend

I have plots for a data set which is filtered differently in each plot. I am aiming to get a common legend, which includes all factors shown on the plots my_hist_z, my_hist_y, my_hist_x.

Example:

```
library(ggplot2); library(gridExtra); library(grid)
z <- subset(diamonds, subset = cut == "Fair" | cut == "Good")
y <- subset(diamonds, subset = cut == "Good")
x <- subset(diamonds, subset = cut == "Premium" | cut == "Fair")

colours = c("Fair" =  "#666362", 
        "Good" = "#D40511", 
        "Very Good" = "#FFCC00", 
        "Premium" = "#000000",  
        "Ideal" = "#BBBBB3") 

my_hist_z <-ggplot(z, aes(clarity, fill=cut)) + geom_bar() + 
scale_fill_manual(values = colours)
my_hist_y <-ggplot(y, aes(clarity, fill=cut)) + geom_bar() + 
scale_fill_manual(values = colours)
my_hist_x <-ggplot(x, aes(clarity, fill=cut)) + geom_bar() + 
scale_fill_manual(values = colours)

my_hist<-ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill=cut)) + geom_bar() + 
scale_fill_manual(values = colours)
```

Potential solution:
https://andyphilips.github.io/blog/2017/04/04/single-legend-for-multiple-plots.html 
uses only one legend of a defined plot, but does not aggregate all elements involved.

Any idea? Ideally the solution is dynamic, as these plots are described as part of a for loop.
Thanks!

Comment: Add `drop = F` to you `scale_fill_manual` call (i.e. `scale_fill_manual(values = colours, drop = F)`), is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Hi kath, thanks this is a start. But now it shows "very good" on the legend, which is not part of any graphs x, y, z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, but is not the most elegant solution I would say:

```
library(ggplot2)
z <- subset(diamonds, subset = cut == "Fair" | cut == "Good")
y <- subset(diamonds, subset = cut == "Good")
x <- subset(diamonds, subset = cut == "Premium" | cut == "Fair")

colours = c("Fair" =  "#666362", 
            "Good" = "#D40511", 
            "Very Good" = "#FFCC00", 
            "Premium" = "#000000",  
            "Ideal" = "#BBBBB3") 

all_levels <- unique(c(levels(factor(x$cut)), levels(factor(y$cut)), levels(factor(z$cut))))

x$cut <- factor(x$cut, levels = all_levels)
y$cut <- factor(y$cut, levels = all_levels)
z$cut <- factor(z$cut, levels = all_levels)

ggplot(z, aes(clarity, fill = cut)) + geom_bar() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colours, drop = F)
```

[image]

**EDIT**

If all your plots are of the same type they can be combined and then plotted with using `facet_wrap`:

```
z$subset <- "z"
y$subset <- "y"
x$subset <- "x"

xyz <- rbind(x, y, z)

ggplot(xyz, aes(clarity, fill = cut)) + geom_bar() +
  facet_wrap(~subset) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colours) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

You can hide the facet labels by adding `strip.text = element_blank()` to `theme` call.

If you're plots are not the same type, I'm afraid you'll have to go with yang's solution.

Comment: Hi kath, thanks for this. In addition, it now needs to be embedded into a common plot as shown in the solution by yang.

Answer (score 2):

First, remove all but one of the three legends, and set the para `drop = FALSE`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
z <- subset(diamonds, subset = cut == "Fair" | cut == "Good")
y <- subset(diamonds, subset = cut == "Good")
x <- subset(diamonds, subset = cut == "Premium" | cut == "Fair")

colours = c("Fair" =  "#666362", 
  "Good" = "#D40511", 
  "Very Good" = "#FFCC00", 
  "Premium" = "#000000",  
  "Ideal" = "#BBBBB3") 

my_hist_z <-ggplot(z, aes(clarity, fill=cut)) + geom_bar() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = colours, drop = FALSE) + 
  theme(legend.position = "none")
my_hist_y <-ggplot(y, aes(clarity, fill=cut)) + geom_bar() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = colours, drop = FALSE) + 
  theme(legend.position = "none")
my_hist_x <-ggplot(x, aes(clarity, fill=cut)) + geom_bar() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = colours, drop = FALSE)
```

Second, using function `grid_arrange_shared_legend()`  in the [post](https://andyphilips.github.io/blog/2017/04/04/single-legend-for-multiple-plots.html) you mentioned above to combine all three plots

```
grid_arrange_shared_legend <- function(..., ncol = length(list(...)), nrow = 1, position = c("bottom", "right")) {
  plots <- list(...)
  position <- match.arg(position)
  g <- ggplotGrob(plots[[1]] + 
      theme(legend.position = position))$grobs
  legend <- g[[which(sapply(g, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")]]
  lheight <- sum(legend$height)
  lwidth <- sum(legend$width)
  gl <- lapply(plots, function(x) x +
      theme(legend.position = "none"))
  gl <- c(gl, ncol = ncol, nrow = nrow)

  combined <- switch(position,
    "bottom" = arrangeGrob(do.call(arrangeGrob, gl), 
      legend,ncol = 1,
      heights = unit.c(unit(1, "npc") - lheight, lheight)),
    "right" = arrangeGrob(do.call(arrangeGrob, gl),
      legend, ncol = 2,
      widths = unit.c(unit(1, "npc") - lwidth, lwidth)))

  grid.newpage()
  grid.draw(combined)

  # return gtable invisibly
  invisible(combined)
}

grid_arrange_shared_legend(my_hist_z,my_hist_y,my_hist_x, ncol = 3)
```

[image]